# "Любовь(,) как состояние(,) прекрасна".

Tags: пунктуация

Любовь, как состояние, прекрасна.

Answer (score 2):

На усмотрение автора.

С запятыми - в значении *будучи*, без - в значении *в качестве*.

Answer (score 0):

Запятые нужны. Здесь приложение с союзом "как". У Лопатина есть специальная оговорка за этот счет.

> Примечание 2. Приложение с союзом как надо отличать от оборота со значением «в качестве». Ср.: Он, как инженер, должен быть руководителем стройки (будучи инженером, должен руководить; приложение). — Он приехал на стройку как инженер (в качестве инженера; см. § 90).

http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=169

Дело, конечно, не в Лопатине, все это и в других источниках есть, просто уж очень подходящий пример. Действительно, легко спутать этот случай с другим, соответствующим значению "в качестве".

Долго пытался себя убедить, что здесь возможна иная трактовка, - не получилось. Нету тут "качества", вряд ли автор что-то настолько заумное  хотел сказать.

Answer (score 0):

> Любовь, как состояние, прекрасна.

***Любовь как состояние -- прекрасна.***